# Convert ListView to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

i have a list view in my app.
I want to change it to an recycler view, but even with different tutorials i dont get it.

I was using this: https://www.spreys.com/listview-to-recyclerview/
I failed with the "getView" part here.

Here is my code of the ListActivity and LeagueArrayAdapter.

Thanks for your help.

ListActivity:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private final int REQUEST_CODE_EDIT = 1;
    private static LeagueDAO leagueDAO;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        leagueDAO = MainActivity.getLeagueDAO();
        List<League> allLeagues1 = leagueDAO.getLeagues();

        if (allLeagues1.size() == 0) {
            leagueDAO.insert(new League("HVM Landesliga 19/20","https://hvmittelrhein-handball.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaHBDE.woa/wa/groupPage?championship=MR+19%2F20&group=247189"));
            allLeagues1 = leagueDAO.getLeagues();
        }

        adapter = new LeagueArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.league, allLeagues1);
        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.league_list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        Button btn_league_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_league_add);
        btn_league_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contMenu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextmenuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(contMenu, v, contextmenuInfo);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.team_list_context_menu, contMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi=
                (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        League league = (League)adapter.getItem(acmi.position);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.evliconit_edit:
                editEntry(league, acmi.position);
                return true;
            case R.id.evliconit_del:
                leagueDAO.delete(league);
                adapter.remove(league);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        League team = (League)adapter.getItem(position);
        editEntry(team, position);
    }


    private void editEntry(League league, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("team", league);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EDIT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            int position = extras.getInt("position");
            League league = (League) adapter.getItem(position);
            league.setLeague_name(extras.getString("league_name"));
            league.setLeague_url(extras.getString("league_url"));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        leagueDAO = MainActivity.getLeagueDAO();
        List<League> allLeagues1 = leagueDAO.getLeagues();
        adapter = new LeagueArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.league, allLeagues1);
        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.league_list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);
    }
```

LeagueArrayAdapter:

```
public class LeagueArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<League> {

    private List<League> leagues;
    private Context context;
    private int layout;

    public LeagueArrayAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<League> leagues) {
        super(context, layout, leagues);
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.leagues = leagues;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        League league = leagues.get(position);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, null);
        TextView tv_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        TextView tv_url = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url);
        tv_name.setText(league.getLeague_name());
        tv_url.setText(league.getLeague_url());
        return convertView;
        }
}
```

Update: app crashed when opened the activity

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private final int REQUEST_CODE_EDIT = 1;
    private static LeagueDAO leagueDAO;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        leagueDAO = MainActivity.getLeagueDAO();
        List<League> allLeagues1 = leagueDAO.getLeagues();

        if (allLeagues1.size() == 0) {
            leagueDAO.insert(new League("HVM Landesliga 19/20","https://hvmittelrhein-handball.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaHBDE.woa/wa/groupPage?championship=MR+19%2F20&group=247189"));
            allLeagues1 = leagueDAO.getLeagues();
        }

//        adapter = new LeagueArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.league, allLeagues1);
        RecyclerView lv = findViewById(R.id.league_list);
        lv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        lv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        lv.setAdapter(new LeagueArrayAdapter(allLeagues1));
//        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        Button btn_league_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_league_add);
        btn_league_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            });
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: You have to extend RecyclerView.Adapter and not ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 2):

I reconstructed your ListView Adapter using RecyclerView.Adapter.

1. `onCreateView` is called for every visible container on your screen. If your screen can show 10 rows of data RecyclerView makes 11 - 12 containers (ViewHolder)
2. `onBindView` updates those containers with new data when you scroll.
3. `MyViewHolder` is the object that holds data about every row of data (container)
4. `static class` and `bind()` function inside to avoid any memory leak in your adapter.
5. We have access to `Context` in `RecyclerView.Adapter` using `itemView` and `parent`
6. `itemView` is the inflated View for each container (ViewHolder).
7. Initialize your Views inside ViewHolder's constructor so they get assigned once.

```
public class LeagueArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LeagueArrayAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<League> leagues;

    public LeagueArrayAdapter(ArrayList<League> leagues) {
        this.leagues = leagues;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_league, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(leagues.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_name;
        TextView tv_url;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_url = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url);
        }

        void bind(League league) {
            tv_name.setText(league.getLeague_name());
            tv_url.setText(league.getLeague_url());
        }

    }

}
```

Your Activity:

1. `LinearLayoutManager` for a linear layout
2. `GridLayoutManager` for a grid layout
3. `setHasFixedSize()` enhances your RecyclerView's speed if you are sure the RecyclerView itself won't change width or height.

```
public class LeagueActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_ACTIVITY_LAYOUT_ID);
        ...
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RECYCLER_VIEW_ID);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new LeagueArrayAdapter(SEND_YOUR_ARRAY_OF_LEAGUE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, after the RecyclerView.Adapter i have to change the ListActivity but i dont get that

Comment: @Philipe check out the updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Updatet my post, app crashed when opened the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the [Groupie Lbrary](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie), it works with recyclerView and it makes life much easier for you, here is an example of how you can use it (I'm writing the code in kotlin but it shouldn't be that different from java)

first, add those lines to your Build.gradle (app) file

```
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.3.0'
```

then inside your activity create an adapter then set the adapter to your recyclerView

```
val myAdapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
```

and just like this you set the adapter to your recyclerView, but you have to create "Items" to put inside the recyclerView. you can create an Item like so

```
class MyItem: Item() {
    override fun getLayout() = R.layout.layout_seen

    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int){

    }
}
```

in the getLayout method, you return the layout that you to display inside the recyclerView,
you can use the bind method to do any kind of modifications we want to apply to our layout that we are displaying.

lastly, we can add our items to the adapter this way

```
myAdapter.add(MyItem())
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

for more details check the library, in here I just explained how you can simply add an item to your RecyclerView